# AngularJS apply filter in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have root controller in my `AngularJS` web application and filter. Filter works if i apply it in the `html` template, but it doesn't work if i'm trying to apply filter in the controller.

```
function Controller ( ... deps ...) {
    filter = $filter('my_filter');
    $scope.$apply(function(){$scope.error_message =  filter('ERROR');});
}
```

`filter` must returns simple `error` string to the `<p>`, it doesn't work.

If i make:

```
<p>{{'....' | my_filter}}</p>
```

It works. Why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't wrap `$scope.error_message =  filter('ERROR');` in `$scope.$apply` - this will cause an error because the Controller is invoked in a digest cycle.

This should work:

```js
function Controller ($filter ... other deps ...) {
  var filter = $filter('my_filter');
  $scope.error_message =  filter('ERROR');
}
```

Comment: What if i want to do the exact same thing on a directive? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202242/assign-the-filter-value-to-a-variable-within-a-directive