# Assign the filter value to a variable within a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am able to do it(title) on my controllers and I was wondering if I can do it on my directives too.

Lets say that I inject the filter to my directive like this...

```
app.directive('ngDirective', 
    ['$compile','$filter',
    function ($compile, $filter) {
        'use strict';
```

And inside the link function I have the following.

```
var filter = $filter('i18n');
var requiredMessage = filter('is_required');
```

I know that on the directive I lose my $scope and that might be the reason.

EDIT: Here is the plunker with the preview of my code http://plnkr.co/edit/u1L9SHdAvZnvEqwVBeJg

Any thoughts on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Could you provide a plunker of your code? This seems fairly straightforward but I have no idea on how you are attempting to go about with it (that is the entire code setup)? I suspect that you are not defining the scope of your directive properly...

Comment: yo @callmekatootie it's pretty much the same case as this link, but within a directive rather than a controller. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775750/angularjs-apply-filter-in-controller

Comment: @callmekatootie that may give you a better understanding of what I was talking about. http://plnkr.co/edit/u1L9SHdAvZnvEqwVBeJg

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use certain filter, you'll have to load it.

Here is the example of defining filter and load into your directive module.

http://plnkr.co/edit/61X6i32By8PA6W7BLh52?p=preview

```
angular.module('myfilters', []).
filter('i18n', function() {
  return function() { return 'my message'; };
});

angular.module('myapp', ['myfilters']).
  directive('ngTest', function($compile, $filter) {
    'use strict';
```

Comment: The filter was being loaded already, still no bueno. Any other idea?

Comment: You might want to include i18n filter in your plunker.  It is not loaded there, so there is no wonder why it is null.